Devolver fila de un array php en la cual se encuentra una cantidad dentro de un rango
Tengo el siguiente array:
$tarifa = [
   //limiteInferior  limiteSuperior  cuotaFija
   [ 2,                       4,      100],
   [ 5,                       8,      350],
   [ 9,                      12,      400],
   [ 13,                     20,      600]
 ];

Lo que intento hacer es que si ingreso $base = 3, me devuelva la fila 0, si $base = 7 me dedevuelva la fila 1 y si $base = 15 me devuelva la fila 3.
Intente lo siguiente pero no funciona:
    foreach ($tarifa as $t) {
  if ($t[0] >= $base || $t[1] <= $base) {
     $limiteInferior = $t[0];
     $limiteSuperior = $t[1];
     $cuotaFija      = $t[2];
     break;
  }


Esta condición ($t[0] >= $base || $t[1] <= $base) está incorrecta.
La sentencia, reescrita de otra forma, significa:
Si $base <= $t[0] o si $base >= $t[1] entrar en la condición.
Entonces para $base = 3, el primer subarray no cumple, porque ni 3 <= 2, ni 3 > 4.
En la segunda iteración 3 <= 5 por lo que el resultado es 350.
Con base = 7 o 15, en la primera iteración ambos son >= 4 y por eso en ambos casos el resultado es 100.
Esa es una de las razones por las cuales en programación es importante que el lenguaje sea escrito de la forma más natural posible. A pesar de que se puede arreglar el condicional con el orden como los tienes, se entiende mejor si el término $base queda de primero:
if (($base >= $t[0]) && ($base <= $t[1])) {
    // ...
}


Muchas gracias por la ayuda!!
